# I can't use my User Control Component in Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, dynamic-usercontrols

> The 'MeButton' component could not be created. The error message is
> as follows:
> 'Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsSeiverExcept ion:
> 'Ecommerce Desktop.Base.MeButton, Ecommerce Desktop.The type 'Admin,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be
> resolved. location:
> Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClient.d_49.1.MoveNext0 --- the end of the stack trace starting
> from the previous location where the exception was created
> ---location: System.Runtime.ExceptionSeivices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Thro wQ
> location: System.Runtime.CompilerSeivices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSucc
> essAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) Location:
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.ThreadingJoinableTask.CompleteOnC urrentThread0
> Location: Microsoft.VisualStudio.ThreadingJoinableTaski.CompleteOn
> CurrentThread0 location:
> Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Protocol.Endpoints.DesignTool
> sEndpoints.DesignerHostslmpl.createComponent(Sessionld sessionld,
> Typeldentitytype, String name, NameValuePairs defaultValues) Location:
> Microsoft.WinForms.DesignTools.Client.Toolbox.WinFormsToo
> lboxItem.CreateComponentsCore(IDesignerHost host, idictionally
> defaultValues) location:
> System.Drawing.Design.ToolboxItem.createComponents(Ide gnerHost host,
> idictionally defaultValues) location:
> Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Designers.ComponentPr
> owDesigner.CreateToolgoolboxItem tool, location, Nullablei size,
> ObjectProxytoolboxSnapArgsy

I get such an error when I drag User Control to the form from the Toolbox.

I just created a User Control, I didn't do anything, but it still didn't happen.

User control and winforms are in the same library.
i am working with dependency injection

Comment: *I get such an error*: what error? -- Post the code you have written for this UserControl. Also specify whether it's a class in the same Project or, e.g., a Class Library

Comment: the visual is not loaded, I'm asking a question for the first time, sorry

Comment: You need to post the exception as text and in English only -- Since you're new here, you should have visited the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) -- See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you very much jimi, have I tried to edit a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was solved when I updated visual studio